# Laravel, how to put multiple value on @if

Tags: laravel

I had a if statement that return 'active active-c' if the getName is true, but the problem is i wanna put two value on it so I do this:

```
@if (Route::current()->getName() === 'sonyForm' || 'warnerForm') active active-c @endif
```

But that ain't work well, how to do that properly?

Comment: You need to spell out the conditional each time. `@if (Route::current()->getName() === 'sonyForm' || Route::current()->getName() === 'warnerForm')`

Comment: it is work too,, thank you

Comment: its similiar but not the same

Comment: It's essentially the same, so I've accepted @miken32's suggestion for a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other option is to ask the route to check if it matches a set of patterns for the name:

```
@if (Route::current()->named('sonyForm', 'warnerForm'))
```

Comment: its more simple and work perfectly for me, thanks 

Answer (score 1):

```
@if (in_array(Route::current()->getName(), ['sonyForm', 'warnerForm'])) 
    active active-c 
@endif
```

Comment: it is work pretty well, thanks 